# Why Monitor.Enter/Exit is not reliable comparing to lock() statement?

Tags: .net, multithreading

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;

namespace Examino.Infrastructure
{
    public class MutexProviderService : IMutexProviderService
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> mutexCollection;

        public MutexProviderService()
        {
            mutexCollection = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
        }

        public void Enter(string key)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(GetMutex(key));
        }

        public void Exit(string key)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(GetMutex(key));
        }

        public object GetMutex(string key)
        {
            return mutexCollection.GetOrAdd(key, (s) => new object());
        }
    }

    public interface IMutexProviderService
    {
        object GetMutex(string key);
        void Enter(string key);
        void Exit(string key);
    }
}
```

I test this class by multiple TPL Tasks and see that

```
lock (mutexProviderService.GetMutex(lockName)) {}
```

reliably lock critical section and

```
mutexProviderService.Enter(lockName);
try { }
finally
{
    mutexProviderService.Exit(lockName);
}
```

is not reliable. What's wrong with manually calling Enter/Exit that are definitelly called with same instance argument?
P.S. Named mutexes code from MSDN is much bigger and more complex than this class.

Comment: What do you mean that it is not reliable? Do you have some test scenario to show us how this code is failing?

Comment: Without seeing what's inside the `{}` blocks, it's difficult to tell. The most obvious issue is if something mutates `lockName` between your `Enter` and `Exit` calls.

Comment: "Not reliable" isn't a problem statement. Please be very clear about what is not working and how you determine this to be not reliable. You need to make sure people reading your post knows just as much as you do about what's happening, failing, error messages, which code is executed, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually an answer to your question, but starting from c# 4.0, `lock` generates next code (read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/) article):

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var temp = obj;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken);
    { body }
}
finally
{
    if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(temp);
}
```